# addEventListener doesn't see change in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm learning django and javascript and i have a problem witch addEventListener function.
It doesn't work.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

dropbox html:

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown" id="okej">
  <input type="hidden" name="artykuł">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text" id="mozeto">Wybierz artykuł</div>
  <div class="menu" id="produktybox">
<!--    <div class="item" data-value="0">baton</div>-->
<!--    <div class="item" data-value="1">konserwa</div>-->
<!--    <div class="item" data-value="2">ziemniaki</div>-->
<!--    <div class="item" data-value="3">pomidory</div>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

myjs.js

```
const choose=document.getElementById("okej")
-
-
-
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'produktJson/',
        success : function(response) {
        console.log('success', response)
        const produktyData = response.produkty
        produktyData.map(item=>{
        const option=document.createElement('div')
        option.textContent = item
        option.setAttribute('class','item')
        option.setAttribute('data-value', item.nazwa)
        produktyDataBox.appendChild(option)
        })

         },
        error: function (response) {
        console.log ('error', error)},

})
```

Here I'm looking for a problem.

```
choose.addEventListener('change' , e=>{
        console.log('success! I see it!')
        })
```

Comment: `<div id="okej">` is a `div` - they don't have `change` events

Comment: Why do you expect that the `change` event should be emitted?

Comment: yeah @Bravo is right try with click or mouseover event.

Comment: I'd bet that the input with `name="artykuł"` may be there to hold the value - try a change event handler on that

Comment: If I set name="artykuł" console shows that const choose is null.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct. All I had to do was to restart server.